# Why does setting a default parameter value make this function a closure?

Tags: python, recursion, closures

I'm writing an application where Tags are linkable and there's a need to retrieve the entire chain of linked Tags. Self-reference is not allowed. Running the following code ends up with some very strange results:

```
class Tag(object):
  def __init__(self, name):
    self.name = name
    self.links = []

  def __repr__(self):
    return "<Tag {0}>".format(self.name)

  def link(self, tag):
    self.links.append(tag)


def tag_chain(tag, known=[]):
  chain = []
  if tag not in known:
    known.append(tag)
  print "Known: {0}".format(known)

  for link in tag.links:
    if link in known:
      continue
    else:
      known.append(link)
    chain.append(link)
    chain.extend(tag_chain(link, known))
  return chain

a = Tag("a")
b = Tag("b")
c = Tag("c")
a.link(b)
b.link(c)
c.link(a)

o = tag_chain(a)
print "Result:", o
print "------------------"
o = tag_chain(a)
print "Result:", o
```

Results:

```
Known: [<Tag a>]
Known: [<Tag a>, <Tag b>]
Known: [<Tag a>, <Tag b>, <Tag c>]
Result: [<Tag b>, <Tag c>]
------------------
Known: [<Tag a>, <Tag b>, <Tag c>]
Result: []
```

So, somehow, I've accidentally created a closure. As far as I can see, *known* should have gone out of scope and died off once the function call completed.

If I change the definition of chain_tags() to not set a default value, the problem goes away:

```
...
def tag_chain(tag, known):
...
o = tag_chain(a, [])
print "Result:", o
print "------------------"
o = tag_chain(a, [])
print "Result:", o
```

Why is this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a common mistake in Python:

```
def tag_chain(tag, known=[]):
  # ...
```

`known=[]` doesn't mean that if known is unsupplied, make it an empty list; in fact, it binds known to an "anonymous" list.  Each time that known defaults to that list, it is the same list.

The typical pattern to do what you intended here, is:

```
def tag_chain(tag, known=None):
    if known is None:
        known = []
    # ...
```

which correctly initializes `known` to an empty list if it is not provided.

Comment: Thanks for the clear answer. I'm accustomed to Python being much more explicit than this. If anyone knows the rationale behind this decision, I'd be really interested to see it.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe as an extra eplanation what happens: Default parameters are simply stored on the function object itself (ie `tag_chain.func_defaults` in Py2 ) and used to extend the argument when needed:

```
>>> def x(a=['here']):
...     a.append(a[-1]*2)
...
>>> x
<function x at 0x0053DB70>
>>> x.func_defaults
(['here'],)
```

In this example you can watch the default list grow there:

```
>>> x()
>>> x.func_defaults
(['here', 'herehere'],)
>>> x()
>>> x.func_defaults
(['here', 'herehere', 'herehereherehere'],)
```

Modifying default arguments is somewhat like changing class variables.